# How to use a personal Android virtual device in Titanium Studio?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-virtual-device

I created a virtual device with the AVD manager that emulates a 10.1 inches tablet with Android 2.3.3 with armeabi architecture. I named it `titanium_7_WXGA800_armeabi` hoping that naming it like that would trigger Titanium Studio to recognize it in some way, but I can't find a way to use this emulator to test my application.

Are there any extra steps to test a Titanium app in a customly made Android emulator?

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I deleted all of the virtual devices created on Titanium and renamed the one I want to use as the one that was being used. This make it work but I want to know if there's a different approach than to delete all of the virtual devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was to install the apk generated by Titanium into my desired emulator, just follow these steps:

Open the emulator you want to test from the AVD manager.
Open a console and paste the following: `/path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools/adb -e install -r /path_to_titanium_workspace/your_project_name/build/android/bin/app.apk`. In my case I'm on Mac OS, adapt to your operative system.

This will install the apk on the current emulator, if you have more than one emulator replace the `-e` with `-s`and put the serial of the emulator you're using.

This will also solve some run out of memory exception when using the Titanium Studio generated emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Click on run configurations there you can check for configured devices.

Comment: but it doesn't appear unless when there are other devices, how can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot run that way. have a look at: [custom-android-emulator](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/142473/custom-android-emulator)

You need to

- Right click your project
- Select `Run as`, click on `Run Configurations`
- click on **Titanium Android Emulator - `Your project name`**
- on right side, select `Android API`, `Screen`, `Log level`
- Click on apply, click on run

This way you can test your application code on desired emulator.

Comment: yeah I read that question, but I don't understand how should I name it in that case, I tried `titanium_10_WXGA_armeabi`but it didn't appear on Titanium. My emulator uses API level 10, has a WXGA screen 1280x800 mdpi and an armeabi CPU.

Comment: but if I create an emulator based on the Nexus 10 settings, it will not show up on that list. None of the screens shown on the Run Configurations doesn't belong to the virtual device I created, is there a way to add it?

Comment: No, I think that would not be possible.

Comment: that's too bad, the Titanium generated emulators are awful.